# How to ignore pending migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails app that connects to another Rails app database. They have several common models. When using console, everything works fine (ActiveRecord queries tables properly), but when using a web server, Rails checks for pending migrations and raises error `Migrations are pending`. I want to pass this check as these 2 apps have different migrations. And just start the server. I tried:

```
config.active_record[:migration_error] = false
config.active_record.migration_error = false
```

but no luck. How can I make Rails ignore those pending migrations? Skip this check? Or is there a way to name them somehow, or set appropriate `mtime`, to last migration file?

Answer (score 8):

Try this in the appropriate environment file in In RAILS_ROOT/config/environments/ like development.rb , staging.rb or production.rb

```
config.active_record.migration_error = false
```

Since rails stores migration information in a table called schema_migrations. So can add the version from your migration into that table to skip a specific migration. The version is the number string which comes before the description in the file name.

Alternatively, you can rename your migration for example from

```
20160801105511_your_table.rb
```

to

```
.20160801105511_your_table.rb
```

Add a dot at the start of the filename. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't seem to work if you put it in the main application.rb

Seems to only work if you put it in a specific env config, for example development.rb:

```
# development.rb
config.active_record.migration_error = false
```

... and restart your server